# VirutalBox - How to use USB based mouse as PS/2 mouse?

Tags: windows, usb, ps2, virtualbox

I'm using `VirutalBox` to run `Windows 1.1`. But this version of windows only support PS/2 input devices (Keyboard/Mouse).

So, Is there any methods to use USB Based mouse (and Keyboard) as PS/2 standard?

Comment: While I have answered this question I personally feel you poorly researched this topic before asking the question.  When one can literally type in "ps/2 Virtual Box" into Google, and the first result, is the Virtual Box manual I consider the topic poorly researched.

Comment: @Ramhound, you really need to calm down, you’re too uptight and act like this is your own personal website and everyone who doesn’t follow the rules to the tee is committing a personal affront to you. Moreover, had you bothered to take three seconds to click his name and see that he is located in Iran, then maybe you could have conceived that perhaps typing in `ps/2 virtual box` into Google doesn’t exactly give the same result to him as it does to *you*. But then again, that would require being able to get out of your own world and put yourself in the shoes of others for a moment.

Comment: @Synetech - I am only providing a comment to explain the downvote to the question.  I don't look or judge a question based on a user's physical location only the quality of the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ramhound mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/679374/820), in older versions of VirtualBox PS/2 was used by default.  In recent versions (Since v3.2), however, the default pointing device emulates a USB tablet device ([See docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal)).  You can configure VirtualBox to force it to always use PS/2 from the [Motherboard Settings Tab](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-motherboard) in the System section of the VM configuration.  Under "Pointing Device" select "PS/2".

[image: VirtualBox Motherboard Settings]

Comment: thanks, but it does't solve my problem, however this is the method. Windows 1.1 can still detect my ps/2 keyboard but still I have the problem for my USB mouse!

Comment: I would also recommend disabling mouse integration from the "Machine" menu of the running VM if that option is available.  Then remember that you must click into the VM in order for the VM to gain access to your mouse.

Comment: @heavyd - I would agree.  The author's problem is likely connected to mouse intergration.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that by default this already happens.

> By default, VirtualBox emulates a standard PS/2 keyboard and mouse.
>   These devices are supported by almost all past and present operating
>   systems.
>
> In addition, VirtualBox can provide virtual USB input devices to avoid
>   having to capture mouse and keyboard, as described in Section 1.8.2,
>   “[Capturing and releasing keyboard and mouse](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal)”.

[Source](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)

As [Heavyd](https://superuser.com/users/820/heavyd) points out.  The actual default in the current version of VirtualBox isn't PS/2 Mouse but `USB Tablet` the manual in this regard is incorrect.

Comment: Your source link contradicts what you're quoting.

Comment: @heavyd - How so?  The default input type, for input devices, is ps/2.

Comment: Sorry, not the source link, but the first line from link in the actual quote.

Comment: @heavyd - Yes. I included it because the link was active in the article. Since I was trying to quote the article I also wanted to make the link active. I was not trying to quote that particular article only my **source**.  I am modifying my answer to indicate that the manual is slightly incorrect by saying that "by default" which isn't the case since version 3.2

Comment: `The answer is that befault this already happens.` “Befault”? Are you using a PS/2-to-USB adapter? because that can cause typos like that.

Comment: @Synetech - Better?  Please go help some other people with the quality of their answers/questions I don't need any.