# Is it possible to use my keyboard's volume knob AND get a host key in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox, on Windows, to create a Linux virtual machine.  The Linux VM works great except for one thing: the volume knob on my keyboard (an Azio L70 Gaming Keyboard) doesn't work in it.

To fix that I tried adding a USB exception for they keyboard, and magically the keyboard and it's volume knob started working ... mostly.  For some strange reason, as soon as I except the keyboard, its host key (right CTRL) stops working.  Or rather it works, but just as a normal CTRL key, not as  the host key.  The same is true if I try changing the host key to any other key.

So, my question is, does anyone know how to fix host-key recognition in a virtual box where the keyboard has a USB exception?  It's really frustrating to have to choose between a working volume adjuster and the ability to enter/leave full screen mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the way to solve your problem, nevertheless I will try to explain your experiences, give some insight and maybe prepare the ground for the real solution.

---

In normal circumstances your host OS emulates the keyboard for your virtual OS. The host passes keystrokes with some exceptions and translations (which you can configure where you changed your Host Key). As far as I can tell the emulated keyboard appears in the virtual OS as PS/2 keyboard.

I guess your volume knob generates keystrokes (like volume keys would do) if it revolves and "skips" like a mouse wheel; or it passes the volume level if it has fixed `0` and `100%` positions. In either way I will call these inputs "keystrokes" for simplicity.

Your virtual OS doesn't respond to the volume knob and the possible reasons are:

- Host OS may capture these keystrokes and never pass them to VirtualBox.

My host OS is Kubuntu Linux with KDE. I made a test: VLC does receive *Volume Up*, *Volume Down* and *Mute* keys only if they are not registered as global hotkeys in KDE. This makes me believe the global hotkeys must be disabled, only then the volume control keys may get to VirtualBox. I don't know if it works the same way in Windows. I also don't know if you can disable the global hotkeys in Windows as easily as I can do it in KDE.

- VirtualBox may discard these keystrokes and never pass them to virtual OS.

My virtual OS won't react to volume control keys even if I disable the global hotkeys in Kubuntu KDE. The virtual OS is Windows XP in my case. At the moment I cannot tell if it receives any volume related keystrokes at all. When (if) I do some further tests, I will update my answer.

- Virtual OS may receive some keystrokes but they may be invalid.

Suppose VirtualBox passes the keystrokes to the virtual OS as they are. [This table](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Media_key#Codes) shows the codes differ for USB and PS/2. Your keyboard probably generates USB codes but the virtual OS works with (emulated) PS/2 keyboard and expects PS/2 codes. I have tried few different keyboard drivers in my virtual XP, none of them made volume control work but remember I'm not sure the keystrokes get to the virtual OS in the first place.

- Some other(?) reason.

---

But you have managed to make your volume knob work in virtual OS. If I interpret the phrase "USB exception" right, you attached the device to your virtual OS, passed it through.

This means your VirtualBox captured the keyboard and attached it semi-directly to your virtual OS. The virtual OS saw the USB keyboard aside the emulated keyboard, installed proper drivers and started to work with it as with USB keyboard, not emulated PS/2. VirtualBox was passing all the USB communication between the keyboard and the virtual OS. That's the reason your knob worked.

But! To capture USB communication VirtualBox had to detach the keyboard from the host OS. While working with your virtual one, you may have not noticed that the keyboard disappeared from the host system. It was then "some device used exclusively by VirtualBox", not a functional keyboard to your host OS. That's why the Host Key didn't work.

To test this you may run the virtual OS in a window, attach the keyboard to it as you did before and switch to another (host) application by mouse clicking. The keyboard will not work outside the virtual OS. When you shutdown the virtual, the keyboard will be reattached to your host OS.

---

The question whether the virtual OS receives volume control keystrokes or not is still open. As for now I would say you probably need some coding to make it work. Either somebody ([you may!](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions)) should implement USB to PS/2 codes translation (if it's the issue) or USB keyboard emulation instead of PS/2. There is an option to emulate USB pointing device (see [this](https://superuser.com/a/679380/432690)) but seemingly it doesn't affect keyboard emulation.

---

#### Update:

OP's comment:

> Are there any diagnostic steps (in the non-USB exception case) I can take to determine how far the volume knob "key presses" are getting? In other words, is there a way I can I figure out whether the "key presses" are A) not making it to Virtual Box, B) being discarded, or C) being passed along incorrectly?

It just so happened that another question about multimedia keys was asked yesterday. I did research and now I know few more tricks. [My answer to said question](https://superuser.com/a/1145369/432690) can be adapted to your needs, i.e. you can use `xinput` in your vitual Linux to determine two things:

1. which keycodes are detected when you use your volume knob and it works in the virtual machine with keyboard attached to it in USB pass-through mode (I suspect `122` and `123`);
2. which keycodes (if any) are detected within virtual OS when you use your volume knob when the keyboard operates normally, attached to Windows.

Note you should use different `id`-s in both cases because you want to read your USB keyboard or the emulated keyboard (probably `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`) respectively.

I have done something similar. I run virtual Knoppix in my normal Kubuntu. I disabled global hotkeys and made sure the volume control keys get to VLC, so they should as well get to VirtualBox when its window is active. However I got no response to them from `xinput` in virtual Knoppix while other "standard" keys were recognized. I believe I have a (B) situation here. For the record: my VirtualBox is `4.3.36_Ubuntu r105129`.

VirtualBox may work differently under Windows but frankly I doubt it.

If by any chance you get some keycodes in (2) then it means this is what you called (C). The codes cannot be the same as in (1), otherwise there wouldn't be the problem in the first place. Let's suppose you've got `250` and `251` (just an example, I made up those numbers). In your virtual Linux invoke:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 250 = XF86AudioLowerVolume'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 251 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
```

This should map these codes to appropriate actions.

Good news: even if everything else fails you probably still will be able to use `xmodmap` to associate volume control with keys that do work with VirtualBox keyboard emulation. If you rarely use <kbd>NUM-</kbd> and <kbd>NUM+</kbd> then remap them:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 82 = XF86AudioLowerVolume'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 86 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
```

I tried to remap their combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd> only but it turned out not as straightforward as I expected, at least in my setup (I need to learn more). Anyway, a hint: invoke `xmodmap -pke | less` and learn from it. Your changes with `xmodmap` should be undone after (virtual) reboot so don't be afraid to experiment. Or better make a snapshot of your virtual machine just in case.

After all, remapping some keys may not be a bad idea, even if there was a way to make your knob work as you wish. If I were you I would consider dedicating the knob to Windows volume and something else to virtual Linux volume.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough response!  Are there any diagnostic steps (in the non-USB exception case) I can take to determine how far the volume knob "key presses" are getting?  In other words, is there a way I can I figure out whether the "key presses" are A) not making it to Virtual Box, B) being discarded, or C) being passed along incorrectly?

Comment: @machineghost I have expanded my answer.

Comment: You are awesome!   Thanks for the detailed explanation and solution.