# When USB keyboard is connected all media stops playing randomly?

Tags: windows-7, video, keyboard, bios, ubuntu-14.04

This seems a weird issue to me. After long time I could find a reason why all media stops playing randomly in ubuntu and windows. When I disconnect keyboard everything is fine. But when it is connected problems starts. I did reinstall of OS because of this problem. Still I had the problem, which led me to this observation. The keyboard works just fine when connected. In bios legacy supports enabled. Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are there multimedia keys on the keyboard? STOP or PAUSE may be faulty and trigger itself with no reason.

Comment: There are multimedia keys.

Comment: It seems this is the exact problem. Can I disable those keys somehow?

Comment: I just removed those keys, since I don't need them on desktop computer. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

One or more multimedia keys may be faulty and trigger itself with no reason. I would suspect <kbd>STOP</kbd>, <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> or <kbd>PLAY / PAUSE</kbd>.

(I assume you use Ubuntu with Xserver.) To confirm my guess install `xinput` first:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xinput
```

Then run `xinput list` and find your problematic keyboard `id`. Next invoke:

```
xinput test id
```

(replace `id` with the actual number).

Press <kbd>STOP</kbd>, <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> or/and <kbd>PLAY / PAUSE</kbd> and write down their numbers displayed by `xinput`.

In my case `id` is `16`, <kbd>PLAY / PAUSE</kbd> reports as `172` and <kbd>STOP</kbd> as `174` (there is no separate <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> on my keyboard). If I had your problem, I would test it like this:

```
xinput test 16 | grep -E '172|174'
```

Invoke similar command (with your numbers) in your console and let it run. Play multimedia but don't touch multimedia keys. You can work with other windows. When the problem reappears, check if there was a keystroke registered by `xinput`.

---

If faulty key is really the cause, you can disassemble your keyboard and try to clean the switch under the button.

---

In case you need to disable e.g. <kbd>STOP</kbd> in Ubuntu:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 174 = NoSymbol'
```

(`xmodmap` is in the `x11-xserver-utils` package). Replace `174` with another number to disable another key. ([Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842970).)

Unfortunately I don't know (yet) Windows way to disable a key.

Comment: I just removed those keys, since I don't need them on desktop computer. Thanks for the idea.