# CTRL+Fn combinations not sent to a Linux VirtualBox VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

Host: Windows 10
Guest: Ubuntu 20.04 in a VirtualBox 6.0 VM

None of the `CTRL`+`Fn` key combinations seem to work in any program I tried (Visual Studio Code, LibreOffice, etc.)

Interestingly, `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`Fn` Seems to work fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Fn` usage is usually internal to a keyboard, the OS is not notified when the key is pressed. The key makes the keyboard send different data upon pressing (some) other keys but the OS has no way to tell if the other key was modified or it's a different *standalone* key being pressed. Therefore the phrase "`CTRL`+`Fn` key combinations" can mean different things with different keyboards. What actual keys (in the understanding of your host OS) are we talking about? Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1143762/432690).

Comment: Those are the standard F1-F12 keys (in combination with the CONTROL key).  The keys by themselves work, as well as in combination with SHIFT or SHIFT+CONTROL together.